# Custom 404 response in ruby (not rails) cgi script info?

Tags: ruby, apache, apache2, cgi

I came across a PHP script that points apache to it when it 404s, so it can do rewrites on URLS that mod_rewrite can't do, like checking version and doing other things mod_rewrite just can't do...

I wonder if there is any documentation for ruby cgi and playing with rewriting URL's. I have searched for 30-40 min but all I get is RAILS related routes and stuff :-(

Comment: Its very difficult to tell what you're asking but here is the documentation to cgi: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html and a simple tutorial: http://coolnamehere.com/geekery/ruby/web/cgi.html - I found both of these by googling "ruby cgi" which provided no things about rails. Consider reading the faq and rewriting your question so its more clear as to what you're asking.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, my first language is not English so my questions usually come somehow not very detailed.. sorry but before I do anything going to see if I get what I need from that tutorial if not I'll update the question.